# Facebook PHP SDK login redirect_uri

Tags: php, facebook-login

In the PHP SDK [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/) I can read:

> If the user did not successfully log in, or did not authorize your
>   application, the user will be redirected via an HTTP 302 redirect to
>   your redirect_uri with error, error_reason, and error_description
>   parameters in the URL.

In my app, when I click on the login button, I'm correctly redirected to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?[...] page then prompted to log in / authorize the application. When done, I'm redirected to the redirect_uri with a huge hashed string for the state parameter.

But ! My app requires two extra permissions.
My question is :

Why when I only allow (as user) one extra permission OR I disallow both extra permissions I'm redirected to the redirect_uri with the state param and NO error, error_reason, and error_description parameters?

What did I miss?